# JUnit testing scenerio for Lock.tryLock timeout exception

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, junit, timeout

I want to test a service that is executing tasks in serial fashion and throws
`TimeOutInServiceException` if some task waits for more than 5 seconds. I want to test timeout scenerio.

The complete test scenerio which I have written is quite complicated and I am searching for simplest solution.

The key points to testing such service are

- service times out **by exception** (not by returning some special value)
- we must start a longer blocking task in separate thread
- we can't exit test by exception `@Test(expected = ...)` because longer task thread will be still alive in background blocking service during other tests

So, my current test case look like this:

1. create `Executor`
2. create long-lasting `Callable`/`Runnable`
3. create failing (that, which has to time out) `Callable`/`Runnable`
4. `.submit()` long task to executor
5. sleep some time, to be sure that longer task started first
6. `.submit()` failing-on-timeout task
7. `.shutdown()` executor and `.awaitTermination()`
8. `.get()` and `.assertTrue()` that first task completed OK
9. Catch `ExecutionException` from `.get()` on failing task and store cause in prepared ref:

   ```
   Exception thrown = null;
   try {
      timeoutedTaskFuture.get();
   } catch ( ExecutionException ex ) {
      thrown = (Exception)ex.getCause();
   }
   ```
10. Check expected excetpion type:

    ```
    assertTrue( thrown instanceof TimeOutInServiceException );
    ```

**Is there a better way to test such scenerio?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code depends heavily on the Lock functionality, then I would consider introducing some sort of construct to provide instances of Lock to your code.  Then you can substitute your provider/supplier for a construct to return mocked instances of Lock.  This will allow you to test specific conditions without having to create elaborate unit tests.

Using Google Guava you could do something like this with JMock:

```
// this class supplies real Lock instances.
public class LockSupplier implements Supplier<Lock> {

    @Override
    public Lock get() {
        return new ReentrantLock();
    }

}

// this class supplies your mocked instances for your unit test.
public class MockLockSupplier implements Supplier<Lock> {

    private Lock mockedLock;

    public MockLockSupplier(Mockery context) {
        mockedLock = context.mock(Lock.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Lock get() {
        return mockedLock;
    }

}
```

After setting up your lock supplier in your test case, then it's just a matter of setting up your expectations in [JMock](http://jmock.org/getting-started.html).

Comment: Actual solution will be a little different, byt accepted for very nice general idea, to think about Lock itself instead of threads/task/executors.